# debugging a Haskell application

Tags: debugging, haskell, bittorrent

After learning few basics I wanted to try a "real world application" in Haskell, started with a Bittorrent client. Following through the explanation from this [blog post](https://blog.chaps.io/2015/10/05/torrent-client-in-haskell-1.html), I did NOT use the [Attoparsec parser combinator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) library. Instead following through [Huttons book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1316626229), I started writing the Parser Combinators. This is the code that I have so far (Still at the parsing stage, a long journey ahead):

```
module Main where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad (liftM, ap)
import Data.Char (isDigit, isAlpha, isAlphaNum, ord)
import Data.List(foldl')

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [fileName] <- getArgs
    contents <- readFile fileName
    download . parse $ contents

parse :: String -> Maybe BenValue
parse s = case runParser value s of
    []       -> Nothing
    [(p, _)] -> Just p

download :: Maybe BenValue -> IO ()
download (Just p) = print p
download _        = print "Oh!! Man!!"

data BenValue = BenString String
    | BenNumber Integer
    | BenList [BenValue]
    | BenDict (Map.Map String BenValue)
    deriving(Show, Eq)

-- From Hutton, this follows: a Parser is a function 
-- that takes a string and returns a list of results
-- each containing a pair : a result of type a and 
-- an output string. (the string is the unconsumed part of the input).
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a, String)])

-- Unit takes a value and returns a Parser (a function)
unit :: a -> Parser a
unit v = Parser (\inp -> [(v, inp)])

failure :: Parser a
failure = Parser (\inp -> [])

one :: Parser Char
one = Parser $ \inp -> case inp of
        []      -> []
        (x: xs) -> [(x, xs)]

runParser :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
runParser (Parser p) inp = p inp

bind :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
bind (Parser p) f = Parser $ \inp -> case p inp of
    []         -> []
    [(v, out)] -> runParser (f v) out

instance Monad Parser where
    return  = unit
    p >>= f = bind p f

instance Applicative Parser where
    pure  = unit
    (<*>) = ap

instance Functor Parser where
    fmap = liftM

choice :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
choice p q = Parser $ \inp -> case runParser p inp of
    [] -> runParser q inp
    x  -> x

satisfies :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfies p = do
    x <- one
    if p x 
    then unit x
    else failure

digit :: Parser Char
digit = satisfies isDigit

letter :: Parser Char
letter = satisfies isAlpha

alphanum :: Parser Char
alphanum = satisfies isAlphaNum

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char x = satisfies (== x)

many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many p = choice (many1 p) (unit [])

many1 :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many1 p = do
    v <- p
    vs <- many p
    unit (v:vs)

peek :: Parser Char
peek = Parser $ \inp -> case inp of
    []       -> []
    v@(x:xs) -> [(x, v)]    

taken :: Int -> Parser [Char]
taken n = do
    if n > 0
    then do
        v <- one
        vs <- taken (n-1)
        unit (v:vs)
    else unit []

takeWhile1 :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser [Char]
takeWhile1 pred = do
    v <- peek
    if pred v
    then do
        one
        vs <- takeWhile1 pred
        unit (v:vs)
    else unit []

decimal :: Integral a => Parser a
decimal = foldl' step 0 `fmap` takeWhile1 isDigit
    where step a c = a * 10 + fromIntegral (ord c - 48)

string :: Parser BenValue
string = do
    n <- decimal
    char ':'
    BenString <$> taken n

signed :: Num a => Parser a -> Parser a
signed p = (negate <$> (char '-' *> p) )
    `choice` (char '+' *> p)
    `choice` p

number :: Parser BenValue
number = BenNumber <$> (char 'i' *> (signed decimal) <* char 'e')

list :: Parser BenValue
list = BenList <$> (char 'l' *> (many value) <* char 'e')

dict :: Parser BenValue
dict = do
    char 'd'
    pair <- many ((,) <$> string <*> value)
    char 'e'
    let pair' = (\(BenString s, v) -> (s,v)) <$> pair
    let map' = Map.fromList pair'
    unit $ BenDict map'

value = string `choice` number `choice` list `choice` dict
```

The above is a mix of code read/understood from the source code of the three sources [the blog](https://blog.chaps.io/2015/10/05/torrent-client-in-haskell-1.html), [the library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec), and [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1316626229). the `download` function just prints the "parse tree", obtained from the parser, Once I get the parser working will fill in the `download` function and test it out.

1. The parser is NOT working on few of the torrent files. :( There is definitely  chance that I might have used code from the references incorrectly. And would like to know if there is anything obvious.
2. It works on "toy" examples and also on the test file picked from [combinatorrent](https://github.com/jlouis/combinatorrent/blob/master/testsuite/testfile.txt.torrent)
3. When I pick a real world torrent like the Debian/Ubuntu etc, this fails.
4. I would like to debug and see what is happening, debugging with  GHCI does not seem straight forward, I've tried `:trace` / `:history` style debugging mentioned in this [document](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html), but looks very primitive :-) .
5. My question to the experts out there is: "how to debug!!" :-)
6. Would really appreciate any hints on approaching how to debug this.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess this is slightly off topic from the question, but given you are working with binary data, using `readFile` and `String` might not be the best idea. I'd stick to [`ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString.html) instead, and all its corresponding functions (it has a version of [`readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:readFile) too).

Comment: Also, trying out your code with the file specified in point 2 gives me `hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)` (which is probably related to my first comment). What output are you seeing?

Comment: I had tried this a windows machine. Not sue if that would matter, let me try this out on a different OS and get back. Thanks.

Comment: I usually debug by simplification.  I've never really parsed binary data, but I'd get one of those real world torrents and simplify it little by little until my parser passes.  That will show me what kind of thing it's failing on, and how to take the next step.  Haskell doesn't really have a usable "debugger" like imperative languages often do, unfortunately (lazy evaluation makes it very hard to give a good experience here).

Comment: @user3169543 Oh darn. I know the problem. I think most windows machines default to latin1 encoding while most *nix default to utf8. [Changing the encoding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetEncoding) fixed it. I've hit myself on this one a couple times.

Comment: @user3169543 Do you have a specific example that does not work with your parser?

Comment: @Alec : Debian: debian-8.6.0-amd64-CD-1.iso.torrent  Same torrent on OS-X work! while on Windows it fails! Can not edit the question, pls see my next comment.

Comment: 14    handle <- openFile fileName ReadMode                                                                        
 15    hSetEncoding handle latin1                                                                                  
 16    contents <- hGetContents handle                                                                             
 17    download . parse $ contents                                                                                 
 18    hClose handle

Comment: with the changes above, I'm able to see this decoded on OS-X, but fails on Windows!, need to figure out the right encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Haskell code is pure, "stepping" through it is less essential than in other languages. When I step through some Java code, I am often trying to see where a certain variable gets changed. That is obviously a non-issue in Haskell given that things are immutable.

That means we can also run snippets of code in GHCi to debug what is happening without worrying that what we run is going to change some global state, or what we run will work any differently than how it would if called deep inside our program. This mode of work benefits from iterating your design slowly building it to work on the full range of expected inputs.

Parsing is always a bit unpleasant - even in imperative languages. Nobody wants to run a parser just to get back `Nothing` - you want to know *why* you got back nothing. To that effect, most parsers libraries are helpful in giving you some information about what went wrong. That is a point for using a parser like [`attoparsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.1.0). Also, `attoparsec` works with [`ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1) by default - perfect for binary data. If you want to roll your own parser implementation, you'll have to debug it too.

Finally, based on your comments, it looks like you are having issues with character encodings. This is exactly the reason why we have [`ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1) - it represents a packed sequence of bytes - no encodings. The extension [`OverloadedStrings`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overloaded-string-literals) even makes it pretty easy to make `ByteString` literals that look just like regular strings.